# Quicktime killed my AVCHD file

Tags: video, data-recovery, sd-card

I have a Sony DSC-HX50V photo camera. The system I have been using for video storage is this AVCHD thing, which consists of a big file storing all the videos.

Using Quicktime under Mac OS 10.9.2, it killed it. Let me explain. I was bored of having to export a video I would like to share on youtube and then uploading it there, so I tried to use the option "export to youtube". It didn't work, apparently it didn't like the format. Ok, so I tried to export that specific video to a standalone .mov as I had been doing. It wasn't keen on that either, and I decided to quit quicktime. It was frozen, and I forced quit.

When I go open the huge AVCHD file again, it had shrunk from ~12gb to 88 mb, and it wasn't recognized as a video file. A lot of free space appeared on my SD card.

I put the card in the camera to see if it would somehow magically recover the file. It detected there was something corrupt, and it "fixed" it, which means it threw the corrupted file into a backup folder and created a new, empty, avchd file.

Is there any way I can get my videos back? I don't have a backup for them, I would hate to have lost them all in such a silly way.

Comment: the "AVCHD thing" sounds like a very bad way to store video. Can you explain in more detail what it is?